# Taxonomy archive 404ing (not term archive)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I may have just dug too deep into WordPress lately that I am not able to free my head & don't get this working as supposed to do.

I want a simple taxonomy archive listing all taxonomy terms (not a term's archive), while it only 404s on my end.

This is how it is set up: I have a CPT **'travel'** and a taxonomy called **'actions'** that classify different kind of travel options (e.g. by bike, sailing etc.). Term archives (with a taxonomy-actions.php template) work just fine. The URL is like www.domain.com/actions/by-bike. However, when I try to pull the taxonomy archive, which should then be located at www.domain.com/actions, I get a 404. Is there something basic I am missing or doing wrong? Isn't the taxonomy-actions.php supposed to be used for the taxonomy archive in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of an archive of *terms* in WordPress. Archives are collections of *posts*, The Loop only outputs posts.

If you want a page listing all terms in a taxonomy, create a page, assign it a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), and output the taxonomy's terms via one of the API functions, like [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that pretty much makes sense, though a term archive would at times be handy. I thought there would be a cleaner way than to use a page and stuff in my code for a terms list (along with posts of them anyway) ;).